# TeXstudio tab to accept autocomplete

Tags: texstudio

I want TeXstudio to behave like every other text editor I use so that if there are autocomplete suggestions coming up, I can scroll to one and use tab to complete it, but the default behavior is using Enter.

I've checked in Options under Shortcuts and Completions but couldn't find it in either place, is there a way to set this behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The next release of TeXstudio (> 2.12.6) will support completion by `Tab` as well as `Enter`.

*Note*: If there is a common prefix on all the remaining completion words, only the prefix is completed by `Tab`. In this case, you will have to hit `Tab` a second time to get the full completion.

Answer (score 3):

This issue was raised previously in 2014 ([link](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/discussion/907840/thread/ef0d755a/)), and the answer was that it was not possible.

Furthermore, the `Tab` key is used (when the autocompleter window is open) to automatically insert the prefix that is common to all the commands in the autocompleter window*, so it does not seem likely that the `Tab` key can be reconfigured for "accepting the autocomplete suggestion".

*See the [manual](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION040), under 'Auto Complete Common Prefix'.