# How to call a TeXstudio command from a macro script

Tags: macros, texstudio

I want to run a TeXstudio command (namely, "Tab or indent selection") from inside a macro.
The reason is that I would like to make the Tab key act as follows:

- If there is a placeholder, move to it;
- If there is no placeholder, then execute the command "Tab or indent selection"

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: yes, it's `editor.tabOrIndentSelection()`. or do you need help writing the rest of the script?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I was going to try to write my first macro in TeXstudio... any help will be much appreciated. (also: where is the full API documentation?)

Comment: I don't really have time to write a full script right now, sorry. I'll come back to this again later if it hasn't been attempted by anyone else. The documentation for macros is just the TXS user manual [here](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION33); The scripting language is ECMAscript. Quite a number of the commands are not made explicit to the user.

Comment: @Troy Thanks! Would also be great to have the full set of available commands

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand your requirements, it's just a two-line code.
Go to  `Edit Macros -> Add`, give it whatever name you want, and paste the following under LaTeX content:

```
%SCRIPT
if (!editor.nextPlaceHolder()){
    editor.tabOrIndentSelection()
}
```

[image]

Then set this shortcut to the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key under the `Shorcuts` settings.

[image]

**Gif:**

> [image: gif]

---

> **A note of warning**. This does *not* (cannot?) replicate the functionality of the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key entirely. The <kbd>Tab</kbd> key serves more roles than just indenting: it also accepts the autocomplete suggestions when the autocompleter menu is open. Cf. [TeXstudio tab to accept autocomplete](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/393601/117534)
>
> I'm not too confident that this functionality is accessible via scripting, so you're going to have to live without this if you choose to implement the <kbd>Tab</kbd> macro like that.